# Wireless in-ear monitors for multiple dancers

Tags: live-sound

I'm seeking a sound solution for my upcoming dance performance where 6 dancers sync their movement through in-ear monitors, while the audience experience the performance silently. Any good, low-cost solutions in the community, by any chance? Am basically looking for a much cheaper and less bulky solution than Silent Disco (if I can use ear pods instead of big headphones or transmitter packs), but equally reliable.

I was looking at bluetooth transmitters/splitters, such as Nulaxy, but it only splits into 2 pairs of bluetooth headphones - not enough. I looked into Audio Fusion systems https://audiofusionsystems.com/: They do software based in-ear monitor system using iphones and laptops - essentially designed for bands to do multi-track performance live. Even thought I don't need the multi-track feature, it would still cost $99 per channel/person.

Are there solutions/ideas out there that can benefit my case? What I hope to achieve is that: a digital piece of audio plays throughout the performance, that gets transmitted into the ears of dancers and crews, with low latency (for dancers' synchronization). Hopefully the setup are not bulky - mobility is very important for dancers.

I'm based in NYC. Thanks so much for your thoughts and advices in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need an RF solution to ensure the latency is low and the signal is synchronized. With a digital approach there will be no guarantee that you are going to be receiving the same signal at each of the receiver points at exactly the same time.

Reach out to any of the local production sound mixers. Ideally you would need 6 receiver units of something like a Lectrosonics IFB R1A and an appropriate in-ear monitor, plus one transmitter unit (T4A). You will be able to hire these units from any reputable location sound hire facility.